# Ruby Hash of Arrays outputing {}

Tags: ruby

If I do the following:

```
h = Hash.new(Array.new)
h['a'].push('apple')

puts h['a']
puts h
```

I get the following output:

```
apple
{}
```

I don't understand why puts h isn't outputing:

```
{"a"=>["apple"]}
```

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: I would refer you to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2698531/749004), which I think sums up this behavior quite nicely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read this

[new(obj) → new_hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new)

> If `obj` is specified, this single object will be used for all default values.

`Hash.new(Array.new)` - by this line you have created a default *array* object. Which will be returned whenever you want to access a *key*, which not exist inside the *hash*.

`h['a'].push('apple')` - By this line, you actually adding/pushing a value to that **default array** object,but not adding any key to the *hash*. `h['a']` is returning you the array you defined with `Array.new`, on that you are calling `Array#push`, that's all.Thus `h['a']` is giving you the current content of that *default* array. `puts h` ofcourse will give you `{}`, as you didn't added the key `'a'` to the hash.

See the same in action :

```
h = Hash.new(Array.new)
h.default # => []
h['a'].push('apple')
h.default # => ["apple"]
```

Now look the code again :

```
#adding a key
h['a'] = 'Bob'
h['a'] # => "Bob"
h # => {"a"=>"Bob"}
#again default vaule as you are trying to aceess a non-exist key
h['b'] # => ["apple"]
```

Worth to read [`Hash#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D)

> *Element Reference*— Retrieves the value object corresponding to the key object. If not found, returns the default value (see `Hash::new` for details).